# how can i delete whole day rows on condition column values.. pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, row

i have below times series data frames

i wanna delete rows on condtion (check everyday) : check aaa>100 then delete all day rows (in belows, delete all 2015-12-01 rows because aaa column last 3 have 1000 value)

```
     ....
   date       time    aaa
2015-12-01,00:00:00,0
2015-12-01,00:15:00,0
2015-12-01,00:30:00,0
2015-12-01,00:45:00,0
2015-12-01,01:00:00,0
2015-12-01,01:15:00,0
2015-12-01,01:30:00,0
2015-12-01,01:45:00,0
2015-12-01,02:00:00,0
2015-12-01,02:15:00,0
2015-12-01,02:30:00,0
2015-12-01,02:45:00,0
2015-12-01,03:00:00,0
2015-12-01,03:15:00,0
2015-12-01,03:30:00,0
2015-12-01,03:45:00,0
2015-12-01,04:00:00,0
2015-12-01,04:15:00,0
2015-12-01,04:30:00,0
2015-12-01,04:45:00,0
2015-12-01,05:00:00,0
2015-12-01,05:15:00,0
2015-12-01,05:30:00,0
2015-12-01,05:45:00,0
2015-12-01,06:00:00,0
2015-12-01,06:15:00,0
2015-12-01,06:30:00,1000
2015-12-01,06:45:00,1000
2015-12-01,07:00:00,1000
         ....
```

how can i do it ?

Comment: Are first 2 columns `MultiIndex` ?

Comment: Yes multi index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need if `MultiIndex` first compare values of `aaa` by condition and then filter all values in first level by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last filter again by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with inverted condition by `~`:

```
print (df)
                      aaa
date       time          
2015-12-01 00:00:00     0
           00:15:00     0
           00:30:00     0
           00:45:00     0
2015-12-02 05:00:00     0
           05:15:00   200
           05:30:00     0
           05:45:00     0
2015-12-03 06:00:00     0
           06:15:00     0
           06:30:00  1000
           06:45:00  1000
           07:00:00  1000

lvl0 = df.index.get_level_values(0)
idx = lvl0[df['aaa'].gt(100)].unique()
print (idx)
Index(['2015-12-02', '2015-12-03'], dtype='object', name='date')

df = df[~lvl0.isin(idx)]
print (df)
                     aaa
date       time         
2015-12-01 00:00:00    0
           00:15:00    0
           00:30:00    0
           00:45:00    0
```

And if first column is not index only compare column `date`:

```
print (df)
          date      time   aaa
0   2015-12-01  00:00:00     0
1   2015-12-01  00:15:00     0
2   2015-12-01  00:30:00     0
3   2015-12-01  00:45:00     0
4   2015-12-02  05:00:00     0
5   2015-12-02  05:15:00   200
6   2015-12-02  05:30:00     0
7   2015-12-02  05:45:00     0
8   2015-12-03  06:00:00     0
9   2015-12-03  06:15:00     0
10  2015-12-03  06:30:00  1000
11  2015-12-03  06:45:00  1000
12  2015-12-03  07:00:00  1000

idx = df.loc[df['aaa'].gt(100), 'date'].unique()
print (idx)
['2015-12-02' '2015-12-03']

df = df[~df['date'].isin(idx)]
print (df)
         date      time  aaa
0  2015-12-01  00:00:00    0
1  2015-12-01  00:15:00    0
2  2015-12-01  00:30:00    0
3  2015-12-01  00:45:00    0
```

Comment: You are welcome again! And small thing, please add to question in future it is `MultiIndex` ;)