# How do I delete rows of unmatched dates in dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter

I have two dataframes loaded from CSV file:

time_df: consist of all the dates I want as shown below

```
0       2017-01-31
1       2017-01-26
2       2017-01-12
3       2017-01-09
4       2017-01-02
```

price_df: consist of other fields and many dates that i do not need

```
Date           NYSEARCA:TPYP  NYSEARCA:MENU  NYSEARCA:SLYV  NYSEARCA:CZA
0  2017-01-31            NaN          16.56         117.75         55.96
1  2017-01-26            NaN          16.68         116.89         55.84
2  2017-01-27            NaN          16.70         118.47         56.04
3  2017-01-12            NaN          16.81         119.14         56.13
5  2017-01-09            NaN          16.91         120.00         56.26
6  2017-01-08            NaN          16.91         120.00         56.26
7  2017-01-02            NaN          16.91         120.00         56.26
```

**My aim is to delete the rows where dates in price_df does not equals to the dates in time_df**

tried:

```
del price_df['Date'] if price_df['Date']!=time_df['Date']
```

but can't so I tried to print `print(price_df['Date']!= time_df['Date'])`
but it shows the next error: `Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: You want to delete unmatched column or row?

Comment: @rahulmehra thanks for pointing it out, i have edited my post. I want to delete unmatched rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i delete whole day rows on condition column values.. pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556510/how-can-i-delete-whole-day-rows-on-condition-column-values-pandas)

Comment: nope, is different.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem an inner `join` can fix:

```
time_df.merge(price_df, on='Date',copy=False)
```